# Sql Rows Count Selection - MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Day1    Day2    Day3    Day4    Day5    Day6    Day7    Day8    Day9    Day10   Day11   Day12   Day13   Day14   Day15   Day16   Day17   Day18   Day19   Day20   Day21   Day22   Day23   Day24   
A   A   A   A   A   A   WO  B   B   B   B   B   B   WO  C   C   C   C   C   C   WO  A   A   A
```

I have the data like above format. I need to select How many 'A' present in same rows.

A,B,C Represent Shift Timing
WO - Week Of

Day1 , Day2 ... Can differ from each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try like following using `unpivot`.

```
 select count(*) as 'ACount' from 
    (
        select u.x,u.y
        from youtable s 
        unpivot 
        ( 
            [y] 
            for [x] in (Day1,Day2,Day3,Day4...) 
        ) u
    ) t where t.y='A'
```

If you want to make it dynamic, you can try like following.

```
create table test_1(day1 varchar(10),day2 varchar(10),day3 varchar(10))

insert into test_1 select 'a','b','a'
--Generate Columns Dynamically
declare  @colsUnpivot nvarchar(max)
  = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
           FROM sys.columns c
           WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.test_1') 
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
--Form the dynamic query
declare @query nvarchar(max)=' select count(*) as ACount from 
    (
        select u.x,u.y
        from test_1 s 
        unpivot 
        ( 
            [y] 
            for [x] in (' + @colsUnpivot + ')' +
        ') u' +
    ') t where t.y=''A'''
--Finally execute it
exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: but here i don't know day1, day2 is constant. It was differ from each month

Comment: in that case you need to use dynamic query.

Comment: @ElangoS, i have updated the answer, you can have a look

Answer (score 2):

You can either use giant `CASE` expression or use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT t.*, t1.A_cnt
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS A_cnt
       FROM ( VALUES ([DAY1]), ([DAY2]), . .  ) tt(col)
       WHERE t.col = 'A'
     ) t1;
```

Case `expression` version would be :

```
SELECT t.*,
       (CASE WHEN [day1] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
       (CASE WHEN [day2] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
       . . .   
FROM table t;
```

If you want only `COUNT`s then you can do :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS A_cnt
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES ([DAY1]), ([DAY2]), . .  )
     ) t1(col)
WHERE t1.col = 'A';
```

Comment: but here i don't know day1, day2 is constant. It was differ from each month

Answer (score 1):

with the unpivot operator like this:

```
declare @tmp table
(
    Day1 char(1),
    Day2 char(2)
)

insert into @tmp
(
   Day1,
   Day2
)
VALUES
(
   'A', -- Day1 - char(1)
   'A'  -- Day2 - char(2)
)


select count(1)
from (
    select * from @tmp
) a
UNPIVOT
(
    d FOR Days IN (Day1, Day2)  
) unpvt
where d = 'A'
```

Comment: but here i don't know day1, day2 is constant. It was differ from each month